# @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) Solo se incrementa una ves

Tags: java, hibernate

Buen día soy nuevo en hibernate-jpa, mi duda que tengo es que al generar @id que tiene identidad lo ingresa correcto a mi base de datos pero a la siguiente vez no lo hace debido a que la identidad no se incremento he visto que no se debe de poner el id en el constructor pero no se ha resuelto saludos.

```
private Integer id;
private String nombre;
public Autor(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable=false)
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="dsNombreAutor")
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
}

public void agregarAutor() {
    JpaUtil jpaUtil = new JpaUtil(); 
    EntityManager em = jpaUtil.getEntityManger();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(autor);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        System.out.println("Se ingreso el Autor:" + this.autor.toString());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    }finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando preguntas sobre un problema causado por tu código, recibirás mejores respuestas si provees el código que se puede usar para reproducir el problema. De paso leete: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y [Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @java88 si funciona muy bien, solo asegurate que no tenga en not null pero si de preferencia edita la pregunta y pon el código de la tabla mapeada

Comment: ¿Qué base de datos usas, y cuál es el DDL de la tabla a la que esta entidad hace referencia? GenerationType.IDENTITY significa que es la base de datos, y no Hibernate, quien va a asignar un valor a ese campo

Comment: @java88 quita este @Column(nullable=false) este es el que te esta dando problema

Comment: Lo he provado en SqlServer y en MySql y en ambos me da el mismo resultado, ya quite @Column(nullable=false) y pasa lo mismo, la identidad la cree desde las bases de datos

Answer (score 0):

La solución que le di es instancear de nuevo el objeto al terminar de agregar un Autor y en este caso dado que no es una pagina que redireccione a otra pues se mantenia el valor del id por que mi alcance es @ViewScoped me parece que eso es lo que me faltaba